# Can't log into Twitter account

Tags: twitter

I cannot log into my Twitter account, I moved into a different 
Country so my phone number doesn't work, I forgot my username and I didn't use any email to create my account. Now I can't  log in.

Does someone know what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Without a working phone number or email address you will not able to reset your password.

As per my knowledge there is no workaround.

For more details see [Help Center](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/which-is-my-mobile-phone-account) page of Twitter.